# float left without wrapping in email

Tags: html, css, email

I'm styling the mail I send to my clients and I want the image to float but the text shouldn't be wrapping underneath it. I've tried

```
#left-image {
float:left;
}
#right-text {
display:table-cell;
}
```

and

```
#left-image {
left: 0; 
position: absolute;
}
#right-text {
padding: 0 0 0 100px;
position: relative;
}
```

the first code still wraps the text around the image and the second set of codes puts the image on top of the texts. I've been using the second code for my confirmation page before sending and it works as how I want it to but how come my mail comes out differently?

Comment: Have you tried using a `margin-left` for the text element?

Comment: which mail program are you using? it may use an old browser (e.g. outlook uses IE7)

Comment: I'm trying to view the email from yahoo mail.

Comment: CSS support in HTML emails varies from email client to email client. Believe it or not you really want HTML emails to be designed with tables not divs and CSS. This is a link to CSS support across major email clients http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/ and an article on designing HTML emails http://www.sitepoint.com/code-html-email-newsletters/

Comment: I think yes, I'm going to have to use margin-left and just adjust every p element. It just hurts my eyes seeing so much redundant code but I guess it can't be helped

Comment: thanks Rick, for the resources. I've decided to use tables. :)

Answer (score 1):

Today I used the align (html) attribute I just wrote

```
    <table align="left"></table>
```

this solved my float problems.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you mixing methods? Stick to one, either float or use the display table-cell on *both elements* .

```
#left-image {
    float:left;
}
#right-text {
    float: left;
}
```

---

```
#left-image {
    display: table-cell;
}
#right-text {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Comment: Well I've found those codes by googling. and the second set of codes works for me in a browser.

Comment: OH! You're building an HTML email? Use tables.

Answer (score 0):

I presume that you are creating the email with ordinary div tags which is not recommended to achieve cross-platform compatibility. Use HTML email structure with no floats as well as margins and then you can see a browser as well as platform independednt mail. Instead of float:left, you can go for text-align:left if you are using html tables.